# Update values from table in same table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL which I want to update

```
NAME   DATE        Tenor    Value
Item1  2016/01/01  1        0.1
Item1  2016/01/01  2        0.15
Item1  2016/01/01  3        0.16
Item1  2016/01/02  1        0.17
Item1  2016/01/02  2        0.18
Item1  2016/01/02  3        0.19
Item2  2016/01/01  1        0.11
```

I want to update values for "Item1" on "2016/01/02", with the values of "2016/01/01" for each tenor. For example.

> For 2016/01/02 and Tenor 1, update with the value of 2016/01/01 and Tenor 1.
>
> For 2016/01/02 and Tenor 2, update with the value of 2016/01/01 and Tenor 2.

Is there an easy way so that I can change my table without hardcoding the tenor? I have a huge table with many options. But the Tenors are the same for the dates, and I will hardcode the dates and the names.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET date = ... WHERE ...`

Comment: @FelixPamittan, sorry, I only know the basics of SQL, I have Microsoft SQL Management Studio, so I dont know if it is sql-server

Comment: @jarlh, I know, but how to select all the tenors for those dates? And I want to update Values, not dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SELF JOIN`

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.Value = b.Value
FROM   yourtable a
       JOIN yourtable b
         ON a.NAME = b.NAME
            AND a.Tenor = b.Tenor
            AND a.DATE = Dateadd(dd, 1, b.DATE)
```

Comment: yep it will work for same table. Take a backup of your table data and run the above `update` statement and check

Comment: Let me give a try

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, I only changed the dates, I set a.DATE = '02', b.DATE = '01'

Comment: This needs a *1:1-relation*... Otherwise this would lead to unexpected (almost random) results...

Comment: @Shnugo - If it is `1:N` relation then we can use `ROW_NUMBER` or one of many available technique to update the correct data. Note the sample data looks 1:1 relations

Comment: @Prdp, sure, I know this... I just wanted to mention, that the given code would run perfectly, even if this was not 1:1. And in this case one could destroy the table with fairly random data without any notice...

Comment: @Shnugo,@Prdp In my case is a 1:1 relation. But as I said, I will take it into account for other cases in which I may not have

Answer (score 1):

Using a sub-select has the advantage, that you'd get an error, if there was more than one value returned. With a *Joined Update* this might lead to unexpected results...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (NAME VARCHAR(100),[DATE] DATE,Tenor INT,Value DECIMAL(4,2));
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
 ('Item1',{d'2016-01-01'},1,0.1)
,('Item1',{d'2016-01-01'},2,0.15)
,('Item1',{d'2016-01-01'},3,0.16)
,('Item1',{d'2016-01-02'},1,0.17)
,('Item1',{d'2016-01-02'},2,0.18)
,('Item1',{d'2016-01-02'},3,0.19)
,('Item2',{d'2016-01-01'},1,0.11);

SELECT * FROM tbl;

UPDATE tbl SET Value=(SELECT tbl2.Value 
                       FROM tbl AS tbl2
                       WHERE tbl2.NAME=tbl.NAME 
                         AND tbl2.Tenor=tbl.Tenor
                         AND tbl2.[DATE]={d'2016-01-01'})
WHERE [DATE]={d'2016-01-02'};

SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip